# Terraform Vsphere Module Failing Missing VM Customization Options For Windows Operating Systems

Tags: terraform, vsphere, terraform-provider-vsphere

Error: one of windows_options or windows_sysprep_text must exist in VM customization options for Windows operating systems

```
with module.example-server-linuxvm.vsphere_virtual_machine.vm[1],
on .terraform/modules/example-server-linuxvm/main.tf line 79, in resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm":
79: resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
```

In my main.tf, I have a code block as follows:

```
# Deploy 2 linux VMs
module "example-server-linuxvm" {
  source    = "Terraform-VMWare-Modules/vm/vsphere"
  version = "3.5.0"
  vmtemp    = "Ubuntu 22.04 LTS"
  instances = 2
  vmname    = "example-server-linux"
  vmrp      = ""
  network = {
    "VLAN136" = ["", ""] # To use DHCP create Empty list ["",""]; You can also use a CIDR annotation;
  }
  vmgateway = "172.22.136.1"
  dc        = ""
  datastore = ""
}
```

Steps tried:

1. Adding a "is_windows_image = false" boolean in the module
2. Also tried adding "is_windows_image = false" boolean in my variables.tf file, but same error.

Comment: This would appear to be an incompatibility between the module and the provider, but  the latest release for each is >= six months ago, and no similar issues have been filed for the module. Another possibility is that vSphere interprets the `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS` template as Windows, but that would be bizarre.

Comment: @MattSchuchard So should I use an older version of the provider?

Comment: What is the guest ID of your template "Ubuntu 22.04 LTS"?